# Conditional static IP address for Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, ip

I have an Ubuntu VM, run in VMWare 15 (host OS of windows 10), I use for work which currently does not have a static IP address.  Sometimes I am in the office and the IP address is 192.168.57.XXX, and sometimes I work at home and the IP is of the form 192.168.0.XXX.  I use an application from my windows 10 OS that is running on the Ubuntu VM that requires the IP, and I have two options to start it - one for 192.168.57.XXX, or 192.168.0.XXX.  The issue is that the IP changes each time I start up the VM or my computer (I'm not sure which is triggering it exactly), so then I have to make a new connection config and delete the old one.

What I'd like is that if Ubuntu detects it is on a .57 network, it is 192.168.57.225, and if it is on the .0 home network, it is 192.168.0.25.  Is there a way I can do this, either in the settings files, or via some bash file that is run at startup?  I am a pretty new to Ubuntu so if your solution involves changing settings, please don't assume I know much.

Comment: Are you using Windows 10 as the host at home? This link should be able to help you; it creates the static IP definitions on the host, not the VM: http://www.milasbowman.com/howto/2015/07/setting-up-dhcp-reservations-on-vmware-workstation/

Comment: Ubuntu uses Netplan, and you could create a [post-up script](https://netplan.io/faq/#use-pre-up%2C-post-up%2C-etc.-hook-scripts) that checks the address acquired from DHCP and adjusts it. However, how can you be certain that no other device uses 192.168.57.225 or 192.168.0.25?

Comment: @ajgringo619 Thanks for the link.  Yea I was thinking this might be something more appropriate to do within VMWare instead of Ubuntu.  But I wasn't sure.